# Hopcroft–Karp algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, bipartite

In the last 2 paragraphs of the paper about Hopcroft–Karp algorithm to find the maximum cardinality matching in bipartite graph:

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64823035/04569670.pdf
>
> The execution time of a phase is O(m+n), where m is the number of
>   edges in G, and n is the number of vertices. Hence the execution time
>   of the entire algorithm is O((m+n)s), where s is the cardinality of a
>   maximum matching.
>
> If G has n vertices then m <= n^2 / 4 and s < n / 2 so that the execution time is bounded by O(n^(5/2)).

I don't understand given:

```
m <= n^2 / 4
s <= n / 2
```

why they concluded:

```
O((m+n)s) = O(n^(5/2))
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
O((m+n)s) = O(n^3)
```

Any idea?

Edited: Link fixed. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct and it seems to me there is an error in the paper - they significantly simplified the proof. Have a look at [this paper](http://www.imsc.res.in/~meena/matching/hopcroft-karp.pdf) where several Lemmas are used for the proof.

Comment: Corollary 5 of the paper said that there only sqrt(s) phases. Maybe the typewriter didn't have sqrt() symbol and they forgot to draw it.

Comment: What difference does it make

Comment: It should be O((m+n)sqrt(s)) = O(n^(5/2)) which is true.